# sending email via a hosted email address through iCloud

Tags: icloud, email

I have an email address (bartleyemail@emailhost.com) hosted by Google, I would like to be able to send emails from the iCloud.com mail app from this address via my iCloud account (bartleyemail@icloud.com). I don't want to have to use my mail app. Is this possible?

(I can successfully send emails from that address via the mail app in OS X and iOS).

Comment: I'm assuming when you say "iCloud mail app" you mean the one at icloud.com?

Comment: good assumption, that is what I mean.

Comment: Is the question that you want to send emails from bartleyemail@emailhost.com to your bartley@icloud.com address, or have email from your bartley@icloud.com autoforwarded to bartleyemail@emailhost.com? OR, is the question that you want to do a send-as, aka you can pick and choose who you send as inside of icloud? Example would be that you login with icloud address, but then use a picklist to choose your external address